# How can I make these images appear normal?

Tags: unpacking, decryption, decompress, hexadecimal

I'm trying to extract some images from a PS Vita game. I've managed to get a load of .bin files with names 00000.bin, 00001.bin and so on, but the file types are not the same.

Each even numbered file is a GXT file, which I have converted into PNG images, but they appear to be cut into pieces, similar (but not the same) to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlODM.jpg

On the webpage where I found the above image, there was a program linked that is supposed to put the cut images together to form new images. However, this program requires both a PNG file and a LAY (layout) file.

Each odd numbered file has this hex header:

```
11 00 00 00 42 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I assume this is the LAY file needed, but I am unsure about how to convert the BIN files to LAY. Simply changing the file extension does not work, TrID says that it is "100.0% (.) LTAC compressed audio (v1.71) (1001/2)"

Here is an example of a pair of BIN files, and the PNG version of 00000.bin: http://www.filedropper.com/binandpngfiles

I'm stumped about what to try next. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure about which tags I should use, please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, if I posted in the wrong place, please let me know.